# How to exclude stages from a release in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-pipelines

I have a CD pipeline in Azure DevOps. There are total 4 stages in my pipeline, stage1-qa1, stage2-qa2, stage3-qa3 and finally stage3-production deployment. stage3-qa3  not applicable for some app features in a particular release

My requirement is, sometimes, for a particular release I have to exclude qa3 stage and  include/run only qa1 and qa2 and production deployment stages.

How to achieve this in Azure DevOps ?

Note: I tried option Azure DevOps -> Organization settings -> Pipelines -> Settings -> “Disable stage chooser”, issue is, it is useful with only YML based multi stage pipelines, not with classic editor based pipelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the stage to `Manual Only` trigger in the Pre-deployment conditions of the qa3 stage.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Hugh Lin. As you suggested, manual trigger set to QA3 stage, in a particular release QA3 not manually triggered to skip and triggered Production deployment stage manually to finish the release.